# Convert a system to multilanguage

Tags: web-applications, localization, translation, multilingual

I have to translate a web application written in asp.net / javascript with a lot of html/javascript code created in the codebehind, which approach could be the best to translate it, or make it multilanguage support?

Answer (score 1):

Move all the text into a resource file, then extend the resource file by an additional language.

Then have someone check the presentation in the other language and discover what a pain in the butt supporting applications in multiple languages is.

Comment: This is exactly what we do... all strings in separate files... runtime language determined by browser/user preference.

Answer (score 0):

We've created a database to save all our translations. You can find a translation by keyword (this can be the English word or something else).

Something like this:

> ```
> Keyword       English          Dutch       French
> welcome       welcome          welkom      bonjour
> assign_user   Assign a user    ...         ...
> ```

In our web application, we've created a class which needs the keyword and the current language, queries the database and returns the translated word. 
Our web application also uses a lot of JavaScript and this hasn't been a problem; it's very flexible.

Comment: Each time you add a language you add a column to the table?

Comment: We never had to add a language since we use this database but when needed we would indeed add a new column to the table.